# Как происходит рендеринг и поисковая индексация страниц сайта

Tags: php, html5, веб-программирование, веб-сервер, webview

Буду писать на примере habr`a.

Люди могут создавать там статьи, после её создания, ей присваивается номер. Вот тут у меня и возникает вопрос, эта статья храниться в какой-то БД или же сразу генерируется xml (xtml) файл в ресурсах сервера с номером этой статьи?

Если работу второго т.е. генерации файла я еще понимаю, то после добавления в БД индексация же не сможет пройти по этому файлу (ведь он не будет висеть на сервере), а сгенерировать страницу из БД сразу по этой ссылке это куда лучше (как по мне), но вопрос тут возникает один, а как же будет проходить индексация? Или так не делают?

Вопрос: после добавления статьи, генерируют файл в ресурсах сервера или добавляют сам текст в БД?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93557/discussion-on-question-by-kitsorik--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того что поисковики периодически обходят все существующие в сети домены. Когда находят новый домен, они запрашивают на хостинге адрес главной страницы домена. Получив ее код они ищут в нем ссылки на внутренние страницы и проходят по каждой из них и делают с каждой страницей то же самое что и с главной. Кроме того, поисковики индексируют все папки и файлы сайта если они содержат полезный контент и не закрыты от индексации например в robots.txt, даже если такие папки и файлы не упоминаются нигде как ссылки внутри страниц.

Как именно сервер отдает страницы посетителю, в т.ч. поисковику, зависит от того как именно происходит рендеринг страниц. В целом есть три способа и одновременно три вида CMS:

1) **database-driven** (которые генерируют страницу на лету, беря контент с базы данных, например так работает WordPress),

2) **flat-file** (генерируют страницу на лету, беря контент с файлов, например Grav),

3) **статические страницы**, предварительно сгенерированные генератором статических страниц (например Jekyll, Gatsby и т.д.).

Со взгляда производительности, продвижения сайта и его безопасности последний способ отдачи страниц посетителю является самым лучшим и с каждым годом набирает все больше популярности.

Comment: а если 1кк статей? Это же 1к файлов, если припустить что стили и скрипты у них одинаковые, то в средем сам файл html статьи занимает 250-400 кб. Не будет ли это причиной задержки?

Comment: [поисковики периодически обходят все существующие в сети домены] Когда интернет был маленький, так можно было делать. Сейчас интернет большой и большинство страниц давно не меняется. Если обходить все не меняющиеся страницы, то потратишь много времени. А на те места, где информация действительно обновляется, времени не останется. Поэтому скорее всего поисковики ничего не обходят. Скорее всего провайдеры сами посылают поисковикам информацию об обновлении страниц.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 я уже делал много сайтов и было достаточно просто выставить сайт в Интернет, как через несколько дней Гугл сам на него заходил без какого либо приглашения. Разве что в последнее время это изменилось

Comment: [Гугл сам на него заходил без какого либо приглашения] Провайдер, сервером которого Вы пользовались, отправлял в Гугл приглашение посетить Ваш сайт. И поэтому Гугл приходил.

Comment: @kitsoRik конечно чем больше запросов ко внешним файлам и чем больше они занимают, тем больше заддержка, поэтому есть разные способы как это решать: кеширование, инлайн стили, минимизация кодов, HTTP/2 и т.д.

Comment: @stckvrw это то само собой, я говорил об задержке при большом кол-ве файлов в одной директории

Comment: @kitsoRik поисковик не "сьедает" сразу все файлы в директории (если это статические html-страницы), он проходит по ним постепенно, как я описал в первом абзаце своего ответа

Comment: @stckvrw это хорошо, но исходя из контекста выше, выходит если на моем сервере вдруг есть папка (к примеру) hide, то путь будет site.ru/hide, а если эта ссылка нигде не светилась, то гугл о ней знать не будет?

Comment: @kitsoRik обновил первый абзац